# How to change cell height in UITableView and Pixate

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, pixate

Im trying to figure out how to change the cell height in a UITableView using Pixate.
According to the [pixate documentation](http://cdn.pixate.com/docs/engine/ios/latest/Pixate%20Engine%20for%20iOS%20Styling%20Reference.html#uitableview) there is a `row-height`

**I've tried:**

setting the `UITableView` `styleId` to `myTable` and:

```
#myTable {
   row-height: 50px;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Am I reading the docs wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the height row with the method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and other kind of styling with pixate engine. Also you should be careful with the IB in UITableViewCell and UITableView row height. I think this post could be useful too: [Styling with Engine](http://www.appdesignvault.com/styling-your-app-using-pixate/). It has an interesting example (including source code).

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath 
{
    if ([expandedPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
        return 80;
    } else {
        return 44;
    }
 }
```

method in your UITableViewDelegate.